# Unexpected notification posting in SDK 26?

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app I recently upgraded to use SDK 26 as compile and target SDK. Now I'm receiving developer warnings when I launch the app on an 8.0 emulator that my package failed to post a notification to channel "null", but my app shouldn't be posting any notifications. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm using Firebase 11.4, which relies on a version of Play Services that automatically posts a notification when it sees out-of-date libraries without respecting notification channels. As this is a problem with the Play Services library used by Firebase, I've been advised by Firebase support that I should not target API 26 until Play Services GSM libraries can be updated to stop firing notifications that don't respect notification channels.